# Django web server : How to restore database once browser is closed?

Tags: django, django-models, webserver

I have to revert some changes done to the database if the browser is closed accidentally or in case of power failure or internet connection down.

```
@transaction.atomic
def populate_db(input):
  object = db_table.objects.select_for_update().get(x=input)
  object.y = False
  object.save()

  //<some operation>
```

During (some operation) if any other user accesses y value its shown as true But instead I need to reflect the changes done before (some operation)

What can be done in this case? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do [atomic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29) operation here. In django transaction.atomic is a decorator which can be used for this purpose. For example:

```
from django.db import transaction

class Example(FormView):

    @transaction.atomic
    def post(request):
        ''' some operation '''
```

Comment: I have tried the way you recommended but still facing some problem. Please refer the edited question and provide your comments

Comment: did you call super in the method??

Comment: No, I didn't call super and also there's no inheritance anywhere in the code.

Comment: is <other operation > is in same method which contains atomic? and i need to know that what you want to reflect here? y true or y false??

Comment: yes.. that is also in same method. If (other operation) passes  i have to reflect y as False which means I  have have already commited it and no need to do again. and if it fails I have to revert back as y = True and commit to db.

Comment: From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests "Atomicity is the defining property of database transactions. atomic allows us to create a block of code within which the atomicity on the database is guaranteed. If the block of code is successfully completed, the changes are committed to the database. If there is an exception, the changes are rolled back." So that means, the whole method has to be completely executed till data is committed to DB. if you want partial code(other than other operation), please use 'with transaction.atomic():'